# Angular 4: show overlay on mouseover with animation based on mouse direction

Tags: angular

i would like to get [this](https://codepen.io/azedo/pres/nywlc) in an Angular4 Component without using Jquery.

I need to show an overlay div with animation based on the mouse direction, both mouseover and mouseout. I tried to rewrite the example code in my component but i cannot get the width and height of the event.target.

**My div:**

```
<div (mouseover)='showOverlay($event)'>div to hover</div>
```

**Component:**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    showOverlay(e) {
        const target = e.target;
        console.log(target._el.nativeElement); // Returns undefined
        console.log(target.nativeElement); // Returns undefined
        console.log(target.nativeElement.width); // Error
        console.log(target._el.nativeElement.width); // Error
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Try `console.log(this._el,nativeElement);`, you are missing `_el` in your code;

Comment: If i console.log this or this._el it gives me the global component div. I need to get thewidth of the target element.

Comment: `e.target` is already a DOM node not an ElementRef.

Comment: So what i need to do? e.target.nativeElement returns undefined

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I like this effect, so I made a component with angular animations: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fftwpg.

```ts
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { AnimationEvent } from '@angular/animations';
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition
} from '@angular/animations';

const animateIn = '0.15s ease-in';
const animateOut = '0.25s ease-out';

const styleIdle = { transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)' };
const styleTop = { transform: 'translate3d(0, -100%, 0)' };
const styleRight = { transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)' };
const styleBottom = { transform: 'translate3d(0, 100%, 0)' };
const styleLeft = { transform: 'translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)' };

export const HoverContainerAnimations = [
  trigger('hover', [
    state('*', style(styleIdle)),
    transition('* => in-left', [
      style(styleLeft), animate(animateIn)
    ]),
    transition('* => in-right', [
      style(styleRight), animate(animateIn)
    ]),
    transition('* => in-top', [
      style(styleTop), animate(animateIn)
    ]),
    transition('* => in-bottom', [
      style(styleBottom), animate(animateIn)
    ]),
    transition('* => out-right', [
      animate(animateOut, style(styleRight))
    ]),
    transition('* => out-left', [
      animate(animateOut, style(styleLeft))
    ]),
    transition('* => out-top', [
      animate(animateOut, style(styleTop))
    ]),
    transition('* => out-bottom', [
      animate(animateOut, style(styleBottom))
    ]),
  ])
];


@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'hover-container',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div class="overlay" 
        *ngIf="state" 
        [@hover]="state" 
        (@hover.done)="onDone($event)">
      <ng-content select="[overlay]"></ng-content>
    </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./hover-container.component.css'],
  animations: HoverContainerAnimations,
})
export class HoverContainerComponent {
  state;

  @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event'])
  onHover(event: MouseEvent) {
    const direction = event.type === 'mouseenter' ? 'in' : 'out';
    const host = event.target as HTMLElement;
    const w = host.offsetWidth;
    const h = host.offsetHeight;

    const x = (event.pageX - host.offsetLeft - (w / 2)) * (w > h ? (h / w) : 1);
    const y = (event.pageY - host.offsetTop - (h / 2)) * (h > w ? (w / h) : 1);
    const states = ['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'];
    const side = Math.round((((Math.atan2(y, x) * (180 / Math.PI)) + 180) / 90) + 3) % 4;
    this.state = `${direction}-${states[side]}`;
  }

  onDone(event: AnimationEvent) {
    this.state = event.toState.startsWith('out-') ? null : this.state;
  }

}
```

Comment: There are some problems with your demo. Even lowing down the transition time to 0.1s if you move fast from one to the other some overlay remain active. I think that a queuque manager is missing or some logic that whene hovering an element all the others falls down. Anyway, good work thank you!

Comment: @SBO It's a change detection issue, an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error occurs when you move cursor fast. I think it will work OK in production mode, but didn't test it yet...

Comment: @SBO I updated the code and the demo. Overlay is removed correctly now. The error is still thrown in development mode, but not in production mode (tested).

Comment: Property 'toState' does not exist on type 'AnimationEvent'

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to write a `Directive` so you can 'reuse' it for each `<div>`.

**Directive:**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[over]'
})
export class OverDirective {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('mouseover', ['$event'])
    onOver(event: MouseEvent): void {
        console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight)
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div over id="myDiv">div to hover</div>
```

If you still want to access to the element from inside the component via template variable:

**HTML**

```
<div id="div2" (mouseover)="onMouseOver($event, toto)" #toto>an other div to hover</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
onMouseOver(event, elem)
  {
    console.log(elem.offsetHeight);
 }
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/vKo8UNsYn06zT4JzPIa8?p=preview)

Comment: With directives work, but what about doing the same in the component?

Comment: HostListener is a better solution, as it's much easier to get access to the DOM element. Plus you don't do it from the component class. Otherwise, one of the ways would be to put a template variable on the div and with @viewchild get the access. updated the plunker

Comment: The problem is that i have this in an ngfor cycle so should generate dynamic template variables and access them with some difficulties. I'm new to angular, i wondered if there was another solution but your seems the better one. Thank you!

Comment: Each div in the ngfor will get it's own hostlistner instance and each one will give you the height of it

Comment: Yes, this using directive. But what about using template variables?

Comment: Can i use the #toto variable multiple times inside a ngfor loop?